# Is there a list somewhere of all the special characters I can type using the option key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

OS X lets me type special characters directly on the keyboard by holding the <kbd>Option</kbd>. For example: — is an em dash, “ and ” are curvy quotes, etc.

Is there a good cheat sheet listing all these keys somewhere? I tend to find myself holding <kbd>option</kbd> and running my hands up and down the keyboard looking for a specific character.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343 or http://kbcovers.com/os-x-shortcuts-keyboard-cover/

Comment: @AndrewU.  Neither of those seems to have anything to do with Special Charcters, just menu shortcuts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Input menu" in the menu bar (to switch on `System Preferences -> Language and Text -> Show Input method in menu bar.`. Make sure `Keyboard and Character Viewer` in `Select Input Methods to use` is selected)

1. [image: Enable]
2. [image: Where to find]
3. [image: without alt]
4. [image: with alt]

And you have your cheat sheet.

Comment: Does not exist in 10.10.

Comment: @jameshfisher that is unfortunate. Is there an alternate way to access it?

Comment: It does exist, it's just moved. System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources. Specify showing the character viewer in the first tab (Keyboard > Keyboard).

Comment: This response does not provide a "cheat sheet listing all these keys". A true listing can be easily scrolled through to find the special character you want. For example, say you want to find this character: „ (a lower level quote like Germans use). This method would require you to press each control key combination and then scan through the keyboard to see if it's there. That's much more tedious than the listing the original question asked for.

Answer (score 14):

There is indeed some software which will help you remind shortcuts.
You will find a list of official shorcuts [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) at apple.com.

To learn shortcuts, I find [Eve](http://www.hotkey-eve.com/) the most appealing. Everytime you are using your mouse to execute a command or action, Eve will remind you of the shortcut which you can use for the next time.
Eve supports [Mavericks](http://www.hotkey-eve.com/release_notes), Lion and Mountain Lion.

Their are two more apps which are approaching an another attempt: [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) and [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/).
They are giving you an instant overview of all shortcuts. Hold the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key for a couple of seconds, and a window will pop up with a cheat sheet. While CheatSheet is free, KeyCue costs $19.99

Comment: seconding Eve, it works well. CheatSheet is also a solid recommendation.

Comment: I would recommend CheatSheet as well.

Comment: Do any of these have anything to do with Special Characters?  The question is about that, not about shortcuts for menu actions.

Comment: @TomGewecke The original question is in the sidebar on the right under "linked":http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121289/is-there-any-mac-os-x-software-i-could-use-to-learn-keyboard-shortcuts?lq=1 I think the duplicate merge was a wrong decision.

Comment: @napcae  Thanks!  I have flagged both questions and recommended this answer be moved back where it belongs.

Answer (score 5):

Apple moved things around. Starting with MacOS X 10.9 Mavericks you must go the the "Keyboard" preference pane, then to "Input Sources" and there you can activate "Show Input menu in menu bar".

---

original answer from 2010-10-01:

In the preference pane "International" under "Input Menu" activate "Character Palette" and "Keyboard Viewer".

You will then have access to the "Keyboard Viewer" in the menu bar.