# Is there any Mac OS X software I could use to learn keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation

I saw a program on Windows that helped the user learn keyboard shortcuts in various applications by reminding there is a shortcut every time he used a mouse to particular task.

Is there some similar software available for Mac OS X?